# Setting up delimiter at required positions in a Unix Flat File

Tags: sed, files

I am a beginner to Unix shell script. I have a huge text file assume of more than 1 lakh records and each line has almost 600 characters. My requirement is to convert the flat file to csv format by putting delimiter as per required positions.

Sample File 1.txt

```
1234567890
9876543210
```

Delimiter at position : [1,3,5,9]

Expected O/p

```
1,23,45,6789,0
9,87,65,4321,0
```

I tried below code and was working when I am using 1.cfg with 3 records

1.cfg Content :

```
4
2
1
```

But as soon as I use file with 4 delimiters in config file ( 6 4 2 and 1 ) its not printing record no 2 which is 4 and printing record as 6 2 and 1

Here is my Sample Code

```
j=`cat 1.cfg |wc -l`
echo "Total split" $j
counter=0
set -x
for i in `cat 1.cfg`
do
counter=`expr $counter + 1`
echo "Printing value of counter " $counter

# If there is only one field in the config file
        if [ "$j" = 1 ]
        then
                COMMAND_FINAL=`echo "sed -i 's/./&,/$i' 1.txt"`
                #COMMAND_FINAL=`echo "`sed -i 's/./&,/$i' 1.txt`"`
        fi
# If there are more than one fields in the config file and for first record generating the command
        if [[ "$counter" != "$j" && "$counter" = 1 ]]
        then
                COMMAND=`echo "sed -i 's/./&,/$i;"`
                #COMMAND=`echo "`sed -i 's/./&,/$i;"`
                echo "Value of COMMAND VARIABLE is" $COMMAND
# For the 2nd fields untill 2nd last field generating the command
        elif [[ "$counter" != "$j" && "$counter" != 1 ]]
        then
                COMMAND1=`echo "s/./&,/$i;"`
                COMMAND2=$COMMAND$COMMAND1
                echo "Value of command :" $COMMAND
                echo "Value of command1 :" $COMMAND1
                echo "Value of command2 :" $COMMAND2
                #echo "If i is not 1 and i is not last Printing middle records" $COMMAND2
# For the last field generating the command
        elif [[ "$counter" = "$j" && "$j" != 1 ]]
        then
                COMMAND3=`echo "s/./&,/$i' 1.txt"`
                #COMMAND3=`echo "s/./&,/$i' 1.txt"`
                COMMAND_FINAL=$COMMAND2$COMMAND3
                echo "Final Command is " $COMMAND_FINAL
        fi
done
set -x
echo "$COMMAND_FINAL" > execute.ksh
chmod 755 execute.ksh
./execute.ksh
echo "Executing the final command"
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' FIELDWIDTHS='1 2 2 4 1' OFS=',' file
```

Or with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/^(.{1})(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})(.{1})$/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5/' file
```

Output:

```
1,23,45,6789,0
9,87,65,4321,0
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works and was so simple.... @Cyrus

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Also can you let me know what if I want to not hard code the Fieldwidths and pass that as a argument ? I tried below code but it failed dhiren.shah7585@Dhiren /cygdrive/d/Unix_Practice
$ cat 3.ksh
echo "$*"
params=$*
awk '{$1=$1; print}' FIELDWIDTHS='$params' OFS=',' 2.txt

dhiren.shah7585@Dhiren /cygdrive/d/Unix_Practice
$ ./3.ksh 1 2 3
1 2 3
awk: fatal: invalid FIELDWIDTHS value, for field 1, near `$params'

dhiren.shah7585@Dhiren /cygdrive/d/Unix_Practice
$

Comment: Use `FIELDWIDTHS="$string"`.